# Doctrine select multiple columns

Tags: mysql, object, select, doctrine

I have two tables: `parent` and `child`. 
Parent column contains field called child_id. 
Child contains no information about parent.
One parent can only have one or less children. I need to select both, parent and children information in one query. This could be done with joins, like `SELECT * FROM parents p 
LEFT JOIN child c ON p.child_id = c.id`. Despite, both parent and child contains several fields that are of same name. But what I want to do is to get child like an object. For example, `SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM child WHERE id = parent.id) AS child from parent` to become object parent having attributes parent->name, parent->age, parent->child, parent->child->name, parent->child->height etc. Is it possible to accomplish this with Doctrine? If yes, how?

Comment: depends on your model, but normaly with doctrine this is just a simple `$child = $parent->getChild()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the association you have declared for the Parent and Child entities. If setup correctly you can get your parent object, and through the parent you can get your child by $parentObj->getChild(). You should be having a @OneToOne or @ManyToOne association in your Parent entity for this to work.